# Button that can be placed on a colored block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I use the `/give @p` command to give me a button that can only be placed upon red stained clay in Adventure mode? I am using this command, but it's letting me place it on any block.

```
/give @p minecraft:wooden_button 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["stained_hardened_clay:14"]}
```

Comment: I don't think you can specify the color for the things (wool,clay) the button can be placed on :/

Comment: Didn't see that question. I have seen it happen on some maps though. You can only place this on green wool.

Comment: @Akidus Could you provide a link to those maps? It may be that they used a resource pack, and changed the texture of a unique block to the texture of green wool (or had no other coloured wool).

Comment: Oh. I could do that. Let me check them.

Comment: I believe you have to be in adventure mode for it to work `/gamemode 2`

Comment: @colorfusion a lot of the maps don't use a resource pack , this technique does work but I think the OP just needs to be in adventure mode

Comment: I can't find the map, but I think that Prismatic and No learning Curve maps had them. CaptainSparklez played one recently, I can't find that one.

Comment: Here: http://vergeofapathy.com/maps/#twyce  The map Twyce

Comment: @Akidus Played it for a bit but couldn't find that part you're talking about; at what point is there a block that you can only place on a specific colour of wool/staned clay?

Comment: @KeithM The `CanPlaceOn` and `CanDestroy` tags are useless in gamemodes other than adventure, but the point still stands that you **cannot** specify a Damage value. It is not possible to have a button only placeable on specific Damage values..

Comment: @Akidus There is no point in that map where something can be placed on a specific color. The separate wool colors being placed are being placed on *unique* block IDs.